# OPT ended Feb 2020. Left USA in September 2020 after 150 days of SEVIS completed due to covid restrictions and expensive flight

Tags: usa, student-visa, overstay, covid-19

I found that From 2020, international students do not begin accruing unlawful presence until an immigration judge finds a status violation in an immigration proceeding, or an immigration officer finds a violation of status in the course of an application for an immigration benefit.

But I found a contradictory regulation here http://hrlibrary.umn.edu/immigrationlaw/chapter8.html, I found that: "Violators of F-1 status are inadmissible until they have been outside the U.S. for a continuous period of 5 years after the date of violation". INA § 212(a)(6)(D),(E),(G). And also on the same chapter, "Now, a non-citizen who has been unlawfully present in the U.S. for a period of more than 180 days but less than one year and voluntarily leaves before removal proceedings are initiated is inadmissible for three years. INA § 212(a)(9)(B)(i)(I)."

My question is, will I be considered as F1 violator since I overstayed? ? Or since I left voluntarily before 180 days, and with the unlawful presence memo of 2009, I haven't actually accrued any unlawful presence? And do I need to mention it while answering Have you ever been unlawfully present, overstayed the amount of time granted by an immigration official or otherwise violated the terms of a U.S. visa?? in DS160 for masters later. If so, how should I explain? Or just say No.

Answer (score 1):

> will I be considered as F1 violator since I overstayed?

No. Student visa abuser specifically refers to people who enter the US to study at a private school and then switches to public K-12 school. See [9 FAM 302.9-9](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM030209.html#M302_9_9)

> Or since I left voluntarily before 180 days, and with the unlawful
> presence memo of 2009, I haven't actually accrued any unlawful
> presence?

You have not accrued any unlawful presence. This would have been true even if you had stayed in the US for years after the end of your program.

> And do I need to mention it while answering Have you ever been
> unlawfully present, overstayed the amount of time granted by an
> immigration official or otherwise violated the terms of a U.S. visa?

You need to answer Yes, because you violated the terms of your F1 status by staying past the end of the grace period, without applying for a change of status.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Clearly understood the first two points.

So I violated the F1 status because I didn't leave after the SEVIS was completed, in other words grace period ended. But since it was due to covid, how could I change the status from F1? I had already planned to go back home before covid came. And was just waiting for the restrictions to be lift and flexible flights.

I am just trying to find the best possible course of action.

Comment: @wonderer: You could have filed I-539 for Change of Status to B2 visitor status

Comment: Thanks. Sure. I actually didn't know that as an F1 student, I could change to visitor status. And also was very much overwhelmed with all the things happening related to covid around us. 
Even though I didn't get any ban as you said I didn't accrue any unlawful presence, its been three years anyways. So how should I explain it when I say Yes in DS 160?
Is there any chance to get rejected?